# WPF UserControl with dynamic headers based on collection type

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xaml, user-controls

I'm creating a **re-usable WPF UserControl** that contains a control that is data-bound in code-behind. The control type I'm going to use will depend on the possible solutions to this problem. **For now, I'm just using a HeaderedItemsControl**.

Essentially, this data-bound control **needs to be able to handle more than one type of collection** and display the results appropriately, with **dynamically generated headers** as well. This way, I can use one UserControl for all the collection types I need, as opposed to creating a UserControl for each collection type (or groups of similar collection types).

I've tried using **TemplateSelector** classes for the control's **HeaderTemplateSelector** and **ItemTemplateSelector** properties. While the ItemTemplateSelector works as intended, the **HeaderDataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate function never fires** for some reason.

So, I need to do one of the following:

- Get HeaderTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate to fire during binding
- Use a different approach to display my custom collection classes
- Ditch this attempt and just create a UserControl for each collection type

Any insight is appreciated.

Relevant code follows.

### UserControl XAML Contents:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Local:HeaderDataTemplateSelector x:Key="HeaderDataTemplateSelector" />
    <Local:ItemDataTemplateSelector x:Key="ItemDataTemplateSelector" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ProductHeader">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <GridViewColumnHeader Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="SKU" />
            <GridViewColumnHeader Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Title" />
            <GridViewColumnHeader Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Price" />
            <GridViewColumnHeader Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="Quantity" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Product">
        <Border Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ListBoxItemOuterBorder}">
            <Border Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ListBoxItemInnerBorder}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=SKU}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Price}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Path=Quantity}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ProductCategoryHeader">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <GridViewColumnHeader Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name" />
            <GridViewColumnHeader Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="Parent" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ProductCategory">
        <Border Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ListBoxItemOuterBorder}">
            <Border Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ListBoxItemInnerBorder}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Parent.Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- more DataTemplates will be created for each data type -->
</UserControl.Resources>
<HeaderedItemsControl Name="Test" HeaderTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HeaderDataTemplateSelector}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ItemDataTemplateSelector}">
```

### HeaderDataTemplateSelector Code:

```
NotInheritable Class HeaderDataTemplateSelector
    Inherits DataTemplateSelector
    Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As System.Windows.DependencyObject) As DataTemplate
        Dim Element As FrameworkElement = CType(container, FrameworkElement)
        If item IsNot Nothing AndAlso Element IsNot Nothing Then
            Return Element.TryFindResource(item.GetType.Name & "Header")
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

### ItemDataTemplateSelector Code:

```
NotInheritable Class ItemDataTemplateSelector
    Inherits DataTemplateSelector
    Public Overrides Function SelectTemplate(item As Object, container As System.Windows.DependencyObject) As DataTemplate
        Dim Element As FrameworkElement = CType(container, FrameworkElement)
        If item IsNot Nothing AndAlso Element IsNot Nothing Then
            Return Element.TryFindResource(item.GetType.Name)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: your HeaderedItemsControl never recieves any items nor Header content. No wonder your TemplateSelectors won't execute...

Comment: He says the `ItemTemplateSelector` works, which suggests he is populating the items.  Maybe he's doing it in the code behind.

Comment: @MikeStrobel in all honesty, I don't see the necessity for this UserControl at all. What the OP is trying to do here can be done via a simple `Style TargetType="HeaderedItemsControl"` in `Application.Resources`...

Comment: @HighCore It's stated in the first sentence that the items are bound in code-behind. I'll attempt to do some Style/DataTrigger stuff and see how that goes. Thanks.

Comment: @BraylenSipe It is strongly recommended that you delete all that horrible code and use proper DataBinding. Also what you're trying to do here can be achieved by simple Styles. No need for a UserControl or the like.

Comment: @HighCore Any chance you could provide an answer/example for the styles? I'm still rather new to the world of WPF.